# TotalJs loop to insert to database rethinkdb

Tags: javascript, database, loops

I'm trying to get the url for each element, but when it goes to my MODEL query it stays in the first element of the array. Any ideas to solve this?

```
var loopAndInsert = function(myData) {
  for (var i = 0; i < myData.length; i++) {
    var prop = myData[i];
    MODEL('myModel').query(prop.url, (err, res) => {
      if (err) callback(err);
      if (res[0].url) {
        console.log(res[0].url);
        return
      } else {
        MODEL('myModel').insert(prop, (err, res) => {
          if (err) throw err;
          else {
            console.log('done');
          }
        });
      }
    });
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
var loopAndInsert = function(myData) {
  for (var i = 0; i < myData.length; i++) {
    let prop = myData[i];
    MODEL('myModel').query({url: prop.url}, (err, res) => {
      if (err) callback(err);
      if (res.length !== 0) {
        console.log('not added already in system');
        return
      } else {
        MODEL('myModel').insert(prop, (err, res) => {
          if (err) throw err;
          else {
            console.log('in db');
          }
        });
      }
    });
  }
}
```